# Reading txt file in real time and update postgressql database using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, real-time, insert-update, file-read

I have a txt file with many rows what is updating in real time.

e.g. :

001;2021/11/16;08:00:12;IN;123456789;123456;John Doe
001;2021/11/16;09:00:18;OUT;987654321;654321;Jane Doe

And I have a postgrest database and I want to update the table with the 4th data.

Here is my code what is read the file (a want to read realtime so thats the reason why I used while(true)):

```
while(True):
 Using readlines()
    file1 = open('FILE', 'r')
    Lines = file1.readlines()

    count = 0

    for line in Lines:
            count += 1
            print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
```

So in nutshell: How can I update a postgressql table with reading a file in real time (in Python)?

Answer (score 0):

Use postgres driver for python, like this https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html and there are a lot of examples how insert and update data